# Setting unique user ID in Node JS redisio store based on authentication

Tags: node.js, express, redis, express-session

I'm testing a simple login function, where a user can login to a frontend react form, and if their credentials match db records, they are authenticated and they receive a user ID.

I'm using Node JS, Express, Express-session, and RedisIo - to store the user ID.

The problem is, although users can login, the implementation of redis in my code means that with each subsequent user that logs in, the latest user ID is assigned to all logged in users, because the redis value is static.

So we need to allow users to store their own unique user ID, without the data leaking to other users. The best way of doing this isn't clear to me based on docs and any help would be much appreciated.

```
const express = require('express')
const session = require('express-session')
const cors = require('cors')
const axios = require('axios')
//...
const Redis = require('ioredis')
const RedisStore = require('connect-redis').default


const redis = new Redis()

app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

//Session/cookie middleware
app.use(cors({
origin: ['http://localhost:3000'],
methods:['GET', 'POST'],
credentials: true
}))


//Init session/create cookie
app.use(
    session({
        key: "userId",
        secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        store: new RedisStore({client: redis}),
        cookie: {
            expires: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, //one day
        }
    })
)


app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
const username = req.body.username
const password = req.body.password

const loginObj = {
    username: username,
    password: password
}

try {
    const loginRequest = await axios.post('https://login-ep.com', loginObj)

    const loginResponse = loginRequest.data

    if (loginResponse.authenticated) {

    req.session.user = loginResponse

    let idString = JSON.stringify(loginResponse.simpleID)

    redis.set('redisUserID', idString)

    // Create object to send to front end
    const authMessage = {
        //...
    }

    //auth frontend
    res.status(200).json(authMessage)

    } else {
    res.status(401).json({ message: 'Authentication failed' });
    }
} catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Login failed' });
}
});

app.get('/home', async (req,res) => {
    const redisID = await redis.get('redisUserID')

    console.log(redisID)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is mainly because all users are stored in Redis with the same key, `redisUserID`.

so, we need different key for each user:

```
// /login
const userIdKey = `user:${loginResponse.simpleID}`;
redis.set(userIdKey, JSON.stringify(loginResponse));
```

```
// /home

const userIdKey = `user:${req.session.user.simpleID}`;
const redisID = await redis.get(userIdKey);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works in one express function ('/home'), but when you try to use it in another ('/get-stats') the simpleID value seems to get lost in memory. I experienced this issue with express-sessions, so turned to redis to try to persist this id to memory.